# How can I link files in Dockerfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile that will deploy rails app but my problem is ruby wont install if I use a docker file. it says /dev/fd is missing. On a normal machine all I have to do is type in the command `ln -sf /proc/self/fd /dev/fd` and all is fixed. However when I put that command in my Dockerfile it doesn't link to /dev/fd. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# Select ubuntu as the base image
FROM ubuntu

# Install nginx, nodejs and curl
RUN apt-get update -q
RUN apt-get install -qy nginx
RUN apt-get install -qy curl
RUN apt-get install -qy nodejs
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Install rvm, ruby, bundler
RUN curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
RUN ln -sf /proc/self/fd /dev/fd
RUN echo "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm requirements"
RUN /bin/bash -l -c "rvm install 2.1.2"
```

I would get an error something like /dev/fd: missing file or folder or something like that. If I omit the last line, everything successfully builds but when I log in to the image I just built and cd into /dev/fd it says no such file or directory. How come it successfully builds but does not link the files I tell it to?

Answer (score 7):

I have tried to use the command you run and it tries to make `/dev/fs/fs`

Try the following to create the symlink in `/dev/`

```
RUN ln -sf /proc/self/fd /dev/
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents: I encourage you to use a previously created container for what you want, if you want to mix stuff just read Dockerfiles from the services you want to install together I'm sure you will find your path, but still I suggest not to reinvent the wheel docker is meant for re-utilization and there are already nginx and ruby containers. Also i think installing rvm inside docker is not a good idea, if you just need a different ruby version you just need to download a container with an specific version you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for this tip. It really makes sense. Yea, I'm an intern for a computer security lab, and I'm currently trying to figure out fast and efficient ways to deploy rails apps. I got it to work by using all the tips I got here. Thank you all, so much!

Comment: A have experience on operations and dude, docker is the way to go!. BTW did I earn at least an upvote?

Comment: I tried, but I can't because I needed to have 15+ reputation. Sorry, I'm new to here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing ruby without `rvm`. Since you are using a docker container, it is already isolated and you will not get much (or anything) from using `rvm` in this context.

You can try building your image from a base ruby image on the index such as `1uptalent/ruby-2.1` (*disclaimer: thats an automated build that my company set up*) or borrow from [its Dockerfile](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/1uptalent/ruby-2.1/dockerfile). Then just add your rails app on top of it.

Comment: cool, this build installs ruby in the docker image. but don't I need to install rails as well run rails server for my apps?

Comment: @user3739610 Yes, you can use it  as your FROM image and then add your Rails app on top.

Comment: @user3739610 you're welcome. Feel free to upvote/accept the answers that you found valuable

Answer (score 0):

I am creating links like you do in Dockerfiles - but not on the `/dev` FS.

You're in a container, you can modify the dev FS, but it gets replaced when you start your container afresh from the created image. See mount in running container:

`tmpfs on /dev type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=755)`